# Textbox as JSF data table Header

Tags: jsf

All example of **h:datatable** on the internet contain simple text as part of table header

example

```
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<h:outputText value="name"/>
</f:facet> 
<h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

But I want something like this -

```
<h:column>
<f:facet name="header">
<input type="text" id="column1">
</f:facet> 
<h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

It's not rendering the column1 text-box as part of table header instead it's making this text-box part of loop only.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this way I haven't got any problems. Try:

```
<h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:inputText id="column1"/>
    </f:facet> 
    <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"></h:outputText>
</h:column>
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand your problem with header. Does it get rendered at all?

By the way, `<f:facet>` must contain one JSF element inside (not a sequence). To make sure that the raw HTML will be interpreted correctly - use any grouping element as 'root' for your facet content. For example `<h:panelGroup>`:

```
<f:facet name="header">
    <h:panelGroup>
        <input type="text" id="column1"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
</f:facet>
```